# How do I hide an element, on specific pages only on small screens without having to refresh webapp?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I realise this may be a demanding question, but here goes nothing.
I'm working on a webapp and I have a navbar. The navbar is located outside of the router switch. Which will naturally make it appear on every component inside of the router. For example -

```
<BrowserRouter>

        <div className="App">
            <Navbar/> 

          

          <LoadingBar />
           <ReduxToastr
            />


          <Switch>
            <Route exact path = '/'
            component = {
              LandingPage
            }
            />
             <Route path='/profile' component={Profile} />
             <Route path='/properties' component={Profile2} />


          </Switch>
           <Footer />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

In this example have 2 pages. `/profile` and `/properties`
I'd like to hide the Navbar component on the `/profile` page **ONLY** on mobile screens (say 767px width). And more importantly I'd like to achieve this **without** having to refresh the page (which prevents me from using conditional rendering or the likes of the jquery `.remove()` method). Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Note: I've thought about just adding the Navbar to the inside of each component in the router. (which if all else fails I will do). I was just hoping to find a more compact solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a quick way is to toggle a class to body element eg. hide-vavbar within your components and with your global css handle that class with a media query

with js you can handle classes with

```
document.body.classList.toggle('hidden-navbar')
```

and css would be

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .hidden-navbar{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Edit: I'd just like to add a small note to this answer because it helped me a lot with just a small change. In the end I opted for

```
document.body.classList.add('hidden-navbar')
```

on the page I wanted to hide the navbar on. And

```
document.body.classList.remove('hidden-navbar')
```

on the pages I wanted to show it. Instead of

```
document.body.classList.toggle('hidden-navbar')
```

this is because when using the `toggle()` method a re-render would cause the class to toggle. I've placed these lines under `componentDidMount()`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can add a listener and react to page changes via state change.

```
class MyRoute extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = { windowWidth: window.innerWidth };
  }
  const handleResize = (e) => {
   this.setState({ windowWidth: window.innerWidth });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
   window.addEventListener("resize", this.handleResize);
  }

  componentWillUnMount() {
   window.addEventListener("resize", this.handleResize);
  } 

  render() {
   const { windowWidth } = this.state; 
   return <div>{windowWidth}</div>
  }
}
```

also, you can complete this to a wrapper and use it anywhere you need to.

```
class WidthWrapper extends Component {
  //just like before
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = { windowWidth: window.innerWidth };
  }
  const handleResize = (e) => {
   this.setState({ windowWidth: window.innerWidth });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
   window.addEventListener("resize", this.handleResize);
  }

  componentWillUnMount() {
   window.addEventListener("resize", this.handleResize);
  } 

  render() {
   const { windowWidth } = this.state;
   // bring children in here :D
   const { children, ...props } = this.props;
   return {React.createElement(children, { windowWidth, ...props})}
  }
}
```

and you can use this like

and your component will have a `windowWidth` prop